# Cannot get simple AngularJS Jasmine test to pass with Chutzpah

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio, unit-testing, jasmine, chutzpah

I have a very simple `jasmine` unit test that targets testing a simple operation on an `AngularJS` controller as follows:

```
/// <reference path="../src/jasmine.js"/>
/// <reference path="../../Scripts/angular.js"/>
/// <reference path="../../Scripts/angular-mocks.js"/>
/// <reference path="../../Scripts/angular-ui-router.js"/>
/// <reference path="../../Scripts/angular-route.js"/>
/// <reference path="../../Scripts/angular-resource.js"/>
/// <reference path="../../Scripts/angular-ui/ui-bootstrap.js"/>
/// <reference path="../../app/app.js"/>
/// <reference path="../../app/controllers/myController.js"/>

describe("my Controller", function () {

   var scope, ctrl, vm;

   beforeEach(module("app"));

   beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope) {
      scope = $rootScope.$new();
      ctrl = $controller(MyController, { $scope: scope });
      vm = ctrl;
   }));

   it("sets the title", function() {          
      expect(vm.title).toBe("This is the title");
   });


});
```

To begin the above test ***passes*** when using either of the following:

- Open `SpecRunner.html` which contains the same references and displays a *passed* unit test in the `jasmine` default test runner
- Test without modification passes if running via `ReSharper` test runner (this tool is not important other than to show the test passes using another test runner; the test isn't the culprit)

However no matter whenever I do any of the following using `Chutzpah` the test fails:

- Run from the command line using `chutzpah.console.exe`
- Use the right-click menu open in `VS.NET` to **Run JS Tests**

Each time the following error is given:

> Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module
>   app due to: [$injector:nomod] Module
>   'app' is not available! You either misspelled the
>   module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that
>   you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

So this is a very typical error if the `AngularJS` references are *not* included. However as you can see above they are for sure included and the other test runners see them and the test passes. The error is identical regardless if I run the unit test from the command line or if I view the output in VS.NET.

I even turned on the `/trace` parameter from the command line and viewed the `chutzpah.log` file. It sure enough is finding the Angular reference files so I'm not sure why the test is failing.

I've seen a ton of posts surrounding this and the solution is always that the references are missing. That's not the case here and I'm stuck. What am I missing to make this test pass using Chutzpah?

Comment: Did you also check the path?

Comment: Yes absolutely. As mentioned the other test runners pass this test with those path references. Also upon viewing the chutzpah log I can see it finds the references in the correct path and adds them to the local test harness.

Comment: Can you compare what you are trying with the couple AngularJS samples included with Chutzpah source (https://github.com/mmanela/chutzpah/tree/master/Samples/Angular)

Comment: @MatthewManela - I have poured over your samples and it boils down to I cannot get `angular.mock.module` to work. I pulled your samples into my project and they run, but you have no call to `angular.mock.module`. I see another Git issue with this: https://github.com/mmanela/chutzpah/issues/444. Interesting thing is, "Run JS Tests" option shows : `Module 'app' is not available!` as the error. If I run 'Open in browser' with the _same_ test I get, `TypeError: Class constructor StatesProvider cannot be invoked without 'new'` Also yes I did add a reference to `ui-router.js`

Comment: I recommend you take the HTML file that gets opened in the browser, copy it and modify it so your tests runs. Once you do that we can reverse engineer to what Chutzpah needs to generate

Comment: @MatthewManela - I believe my answer sheds some light potentially. If you can validate my findings to be accurate that would help. I think the other issues may have been red herrings to the real cause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe through thorough testing I have determined the cause. The issue is most likely that I'm using `ES6` classes in my `Angular` `.js` files being used in my tests.

The issue is `PhantomJS` which `Chutzpah` uses does *not* support `ES6` and the `class` keyword and thus it fails (see [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-es6-shim) for validation). I was able to reproduce in a non `Angular` sample. I used an old fashioned `ES5` style `IIFE` and the simple test now passed. This is why it worked in `Chrome` and in `ReSharper` which used `Chrome` as the default test browser and Chrome supports the `ES6` `class` keyword. If I make `ReSharper` use `PhantomJS` instead of `Chrome`, then my simple test also fails.

The root problem appears to be `PhantomJS` and its lack of support for `ES6` syntax.

Here is a blog post I wrote on my findings after pulling my hair out on this for a couple of weeks. It explains more in detail about the issues with writing non-ES5 complaint code and using that with Chutzpah and PhantomJS:

[Chutzpah and non-ES5 JavaScript for Unit Testing is Problematic](http://www.allenconway.net/2016/05/chutzpah-and-non-es5-javascript-for.html)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using a [chutzpah.json settings file](https://github.com/mmanela/chutzpah/wiki/Chutzpah.json-Settings-File) for angular projects. I placed mine at the root of my project, next to the web.config. You can specify the dependencies in one place this way, which is very helpful as the angular project grows rapidly. I can't know for sure, but I think yours would look something like the following:

```
{
  "Framework": "jasmine",
  "FrameworkVersion": "1",
  "References": [
    { "Path": "./Scripts/angular/angular.js" },
    {        
      "Path": "./Scripts/angular",
      "Includes": [ "*.js" ]
    },
    { "Path": "./Scripts/angular-ui/ui-bootstrap.js" },   
    { "Path": "./app/app.js" },
    {        
      "Path": "./app",
      "Includes": [ "*.js" ]
    }                 
  ],
  "Tests": [
    { "Includes": [ "*.spec.js" ] }
  ]
}
```

This will run on jasmine version 1. I'm not sure how you  It will include everything that matches  "./Scripts/angular*.js" and everything that matches "./app/*.js" (including sub-directories). As you add new angular references and app modules, you should not need to modify this configuration (once you get it working).

Comment: As a FYI I had already tried this (add the .json settings file) and couldn't get it working. That's when I decided to simplify things way down and just get a _single_ targeted unit test targeting AngularJS using Chutzpah to work. If I can get my simple example working I'll move back to using a settings file.

Comment: I was never successful the simple way, but my code had so many dependencies, it went off the screen. Hopefully you can figure it out and let us know. Did the settings file I provided fail as well?

Comment: 1st off I'm using `v2`. 2nd, That settings file is customized for file paths specific to your project so it wouldn't work exactly as mine does. However my settings file did contain the `Framework`, `References`, and `Tests` section.